# share image didn't work android

Tags: android

I try all codes found in this issue please help if it already works with you. Thanks

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.egyapps.emmawatson/drawable/emma_1");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);<br>
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I sure that problem in `Uri` I read images from drawable folder. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Few, if any, Android apps are set up with an `<intent-filter>` that handles the `android.resource` scheme. Either copy the file to internal storage and [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), or just [use my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) (which streams resources), to have a `content` `Uri` instead.